# Download just .html files over FTP

Tags: ftp

In a website maintenance job, my client has an FTP server with the website on. Fairly standard (albeit outdated) stuff.

I need to do a find-and-replace over most of the HTML files to change the navigation. To do that effectively, I'd need to do that locally.

The FTP server is *full* of rubbish. The guy has been using it to exchange files with his clients. I want to get a copy of all the relevant files but at the same time, I don't want to waste time downloading dozens of gigabytes of stuff I'll never need.

The FTP is mounted in `~/.gvfs` at the moment. Is there something quick and easy I can do to copy all the .html files out, keeping the directory structure so that when I'm done working on the files, I can just copy them back using merge/replace?

Comment: I don't have the time at the moment to write a script, but here's how I'd do it: 1) copy the directory structure using `find . -type d` and `mkdir -p` 2) copy the files using `find . -name '*.html'` and `cp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the Filezilla FTP client.  It has the ability to create custom file filters from the View menu to only show certain types of files.

Comment: Good call`````````````

Answer (score 1):

I didn't test this but the following should work:

```
rsync -av --include "*/" --include "*.html" --exclude "*" ~/.gvfs/. /path/to/destination
```

Comment: I did try rsync first actually. Kept coming back with `rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1060) [sender=3.0.7]` (I don't know what the previous errors were because they weren't outputted)